# Java Pass By Value and reference

Tags: java, pass-by-reference, pass-by-value

I have the following code. I can't, however, understand it's behavior about pass by value and reference.

```
class Dog{
    String name;
    int x=100;
    
    Dog(String name){
        this.name = name;
    }
    
    public String getName(){
        return this.name;
    }
}
class Demo{
    public static void main( String[] args ){
        Dog aDog = new Dog("Tom");
        foo(aDog);

        if (aDog.getName().equals("Tom")) { //true
            System.out.println( "Java passes by value."+ aDog.getName());
            System.out.println( aDog.x);

        } else if (aDog.getName().equals("Taz")) {
            System.out.println( "Java passes by reference." );
        }
    }

    public static void foo(Dog d) {
        ++d.x;
        d = new Dog("Taz");
        ++d.x;
    }
}
```

This will provide output as

> Java passes by value.Tom
>
> 101

Why is the output `101`? I was expecting output `102`.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40480/is-java-pass-by-reference-or-pass-by-value?rq=1 might be worth a read

Comment: Java is always **Pass By Value**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're incrementing `x` twice, but on different dogs. Look at this code:

```
public static void foo(Dog d) {
    ++d.x;
    d = new Dog("Taz");
    ++d.x;
}
```

Initially, `d` refers to the dog with a name of `Tom`, with `x=100`. That isn't a copy of the original object - it's a reference to the same object. Java passes the reference by value, which isn't the same as either passing an object by value *or* passing an object by reference. It's important to understand that the value of `aDog` in `main` isn't a `Dog` object - it's a reference to a `Dog` object. The value of that reference is passed, by value, to your `foo` method... so the initial value of `d` is the same as the value of `aDog`. Further changes to the `d` variable itself (rather than the object its value refers to) do *not* change the `aDog` variable.

So, looking at the rest of `foo`:

- After the `++d.x`, `d` refers to the dog with a name of `Tom`, with `x=101`.
- After `d = new Dog("Taz")`, `d` refers to a dog with a name of `Taz`, with `x=100`.
- After the `++d.x`, `d` refers to the dog with a name of `Taz`, with `x=101`.

The calling code only ever knows about the dog with a name of `Tom`, so it prints out Tom 101.

Comment: Thanks @Jon But the next thing is why it prints Tom Object details without printing Taz object details. According to my opinion I thought java pass copy of Tom object to foo method. But t will not pass copy according to this.

Comment: @SaveendraSriEkanayake: No, it passes a copy of the *reference*, as the initial value of `d`. I've edited the answer to give more information - see if that helps.

Answer (score 3):

You increment `x` once, on the dog that was given to the method ("Tom").

Then you create a **new** dog, called Taz.

You then increment `x` for that second dog. It won't affect the original one, and both dogs will be at 101.

As for why the calling method still refers to "Tom", even though you changed your local variable to point at "Taz": That's because a local variable is just that: local to the place it is used. The caller does not care about what you do with it later, its own variable will still point at "Tom".

Because Java does not support pass-by-reference or "out parameters", there is nothing the called function can do to change the value of variables in the calling function.

But note that objects are not stored in variables. Only a pointer to them is stored there. The actual object instance itself is in a shared location (the program heap memory). So the called method can indeed *change the object*. But it cannot assign a different object into the calling function.

---

Takeaway:  Make your local variables `final`, especially method parameters. Then you cannot reuse the same variable for two different things, and the code becomes less confusing.

Comment: Thanks.. But the thing is d reference is referring Taz object but out put provide Tom object with value 101 with increment.

Answer (score 2):

Java is always **Pass By Value**:

main():

```
Dog aDog = new Dog("Tom"); // {name="Tom", x=100}
```

foo():

```
++d.x;                     // {name="Tom", x=101}
d = new Dog("Taz");        // {name="Taz", x=100}
++d.x;                     // {name="Taz", x=101}
```

However, you can get entirely new copy but you need to return it.

In main(): update this line

`foo(aDog);`

to

`aDog = foo(aDog);`

also update foo() as:

```
public static Dog foo(Dog d) {
  ...
  return d;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

When you use the `new` keyword like this `d = new Dog("Taz");`
 
You create a new `Dog`, the new `Dog` it's called `Taz` and have `x=101`, so you don't increment `d.x` 2 times for the same Dog